# Iteration variable of different type than collection?

Tags: c#, foreach, nullable

I have a collection of nullable ints.

Why does compiler allows to iteration variable be of type **int** not **int?** ?

```
        List<int?> nullableInts = new List<int?>{1,2,3,null};
        List<int> normalInts = new List<int>();


        //Runtime exception when encounter null value
        //Why not compilation exception? 
        foreach (int i in nullableInts)
        {
         //do sth
        }
```

Of course I should pay attention to what I iterate through but it would be nice if compiler reprimanded me:) Like here:

```
        foreach (bool i in collection)
        {
          // do sth 
        }

       //Error 1 Cannot convert type 'int' to 'bool'
```

Comment: The error looks normal to me. You can convert from int? to int, but you cannot convert an int to bool.

Comment: @Adrian I don't think this explanation is correct. What if I had string instead of bool. Int can be converted to string but compiler would stil protest.

Comment: Int cannot be converted to string. No implicit or explicit conversion is defined. If u are referring to the ToString() method then that is a different thing.

Comment: @AZ Yes I know, I just gave example to Adrian that compiler shows error because bool is inconvertive to int, so does with string despite the fact that int is convertible to string.

Comment: Thanks for comments @Dan thanks for explanation, my conclusion was wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Update

OK, originally I said "the compiler adds casts to a `foreach` loop." This isn't *strictly* accurate: it won't *always* add casts. Here's what's really happening.

First of all, when you have this `foreach` loop:

```
foreach (int x in collection)
{
}
```

...here is the basic outline (in pseudo-C#) of what the compiler creates:

```
int x;
[object] e;
try
{
    e = collection.GetEnumerator();
    while (e.MoveNext())
    {
        x = [cast if possible]e.Current;
    }
}
finally
{
    [dispose of e if necessary]
}
```

***What?*** I hear you saying. *What do you mean by `[object]`?"*

Here's what I mean. The `foreach` loop actually requires *no interface*, which means it's actually a little bit magical. It only requires that the type of object being enumerated exposes a `GetEnumerator` method, which in turn must provide an instance of some type that provides a `MoveNext` and a `Current` property.

So I wrote `[object]` because the type of `e` does not necessarily have to be an implementation of `IEnumerator<int>`, or even `IEnumerator` -- which also means it doesn't necessarily have to implement `IDisposable` (hence the `[dispose if necessary]` part).

The part of the code we care about for the purpose of answering this question is the part where I wrote `[cast if possible]`. Clearly, since the compiler doesn't require an actual `IEnumerator<T>` or `IEnumerator` implementation, the type of `e.Current` cannot be assumed to be `T`, `object` or anything in between. Instead, the compiler determines the type of `e.Current` based on the type returned by `GetEnumerator` at compile time. Then the following happens:

1. If the type *is* the type of the local variable (`x` in the above example), a straight assignment is used.
2. If the type is *convertible* to the type of the local variable (by which I mean, a legal cast exists from the type of `e.Current` to the type of `x`), a cast is inserted.
3. Otherwise, the compiler will raise an error.

So in the scenario of enumerating over a `List<int?>`, we get to step 2 and the compiler sees that the `List<int?>.Enumerator` type's `Current` property is of type `int?`, which can be explicitly cast to `int`.

So the line can be compiled to the equivalent of this:

```
x = (int)e.Current;
```

Now, what does the `explicit` operator look like for `Nullable<int>`?

According to Reflector:

```
public static explicit operator T(T? value)
{
    return value.Value;
}
```

So [the behavior described by Kent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3709167/iteration-variable-of-different-type-than-collection/3709186#3709186) is, as far as I can tell, simply a compiler optimization: the `(int)e.Current` explicit cast is inlined.

As a general answer to your question, I stick by my assertion that the compiler inserts casts in a `foreach` loop where needed.

---

## Original Answer

The compiler automatically inserts casts where needed in a `foreach` loop for the simple reason that before generics there was no `IEnumerable<T>` interface, only `IEnumerable`*. The `IEnumerable` interface exposes an `IEnumerator`, which in turn provides access to a `Current` property of type `object`.

So unless the compiler performed the cast for you, in olden times, the only way you could've used `foreach` would've been with a local variable of type `object`, which obviously would've sucked.

<sub>*And actually, [`foreach` doesn't require any interface at all](http://philosopherdeveloper.wordpress.com/2010/08/28/pop-quiz-how-do-you-make-your-type-enumerable-using-the-foreach-keyword/) -- only the `GetEnumerator` method and an accompanying type with a `MoveNext` and a `Current`.</sub>

Comment: By default, won't `IEnumerable<T>`'s `GetEnumerator` be called, making the `foreach` "generic"?

Comment: @strager: Yes, but there will still be a cast.

Comment: @Slaks: there is no cast and having one would negate some of the performance benefits of generics. Check my post.

Answer (score 4):

Because the C# compiler dereferences the `Nullable<T>` for you.

If you write this code:

```
        var list = new List<int?>()
        {
            1,
            null
        };

        foreach (int? i in list)
        {
            if (!i.HasValue)
            {
                continue;
            }

            Console.WriteLine(i.GetType());
        }

        foreach (int i in list)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i.GetType());
        }
```

The C# compiler produces:

```
foreach (int? i in list)
{
    if (i.HasValue)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(i.GetType());
    }
}
foreach (int? CS$0$0000 in list)
{
    Console.WriteLine(CS$0$0000.Value.GetType());
}
```

Note the explicit dereferencing of `Nullable<int>.Value`. This is a testament to how ingrained the `Nullable<T>` structure is in the runtime.

Comment: The link you provided explicitly writes that the operator is `explicit`.  Am I missing something...?

Comment: @strager: nope, you're right. It's `T` -> `Nullable<T>` that is implicit. Have updated my answer.

Comment: "This is a testament to how ingrained the `Nullable<T>` structure is in the runtime."  I don't see what this has to do with the runtime at all.  I think your answer is correct except your conclusion.

Comment: @strager: as long as we're picking nits: it's not a conclusion, it's an observation related to the conclusion. The conclusion was that the compiler is injecting an explicit dereferencing of the `Nullable<T>.Value` property. The fact that the C# compiler has intimate knowledge of `Nullable<T>` speaks to its special status in the platform.

Comment: While the info in this answer is useful, I feel that your opening statement is misleading: "Because the C# compiler dereferences the `Nullable<T>` for you." To me this implies that the behavior the OP is seeing is a special case specific to enumerating over a sequence of some nullable type. But it isn't. You can also do `foreach (int x in listOfDoubles)` or `foreach (double x in listOfFloats)`, for example.

Comment: @Kent: After having re-checked the spec there seems actually to be no special treatment of `Nullable<T>` here at all. What you see in the output here is simply the implementation of the explicit cast operator for conversions from  `Nullable<T>` to `T`.

Comment: @Kent Boogaart, No; I do disagree with your conclusion, and I agree with the conclusions of @Dan Tao and @0xA3.  And your reiteration of the statement I quoted doesn't state anything about the runtime, which strengthens my statement: the interaction between `foreach` and `Nullable<T>` has nothing to do with the runtime.

Answer (score 3):

The behavior you are observing is according to section *8.8.4 The foreach statement* of the C# language specification. This section defines the semantics of the `foreach` statement as follows:

> [...] The above steps, if successful, unambiguously produce a collection type `C`, enumerator type `E` and element type `T`. A `foreach` statement of the form
>
> ```
> foreach (V v in x) embedded-statement
> ```
>
> is then expanded to:
>
> ```
> {
>     E e = ((C)(x)).GetEnumerator();
>     try {
>         V v;
>         while (e.MoveNext()) {
>             v = (V)(T)e.Current;
>             embedded-statement
>         }
>     }
>     finally {
>         // Dispose e
>     }
> }
> ```

According to the rules defined in the specification, in your sample the *collection type* would be  `List<int?>`, the *enumerator type* would be `List<int?>.Enumerator` and the element type would be `int?`.

If you fill this information into the above code snippet you will see that `int?` is explicitly cast to `int` by calling [`Nullable<T> Explicit Conversion (Nullable<T> to T)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131345.aspx). The implemenation of this explicit cast operator is, as described by Kent, to simply return the `Nullable<T>.Value` property.

Comment: Gah, I spent way too long updating my answer to realize you basically covered the same ground in your own! One thing, though: I think *enumerator type* in the example is actually `List<int?>.Enumerator`, *not* `IEnumerator<int?>`. Am I right?